# AOSP build error ninja failed with: exit status 1

Tags: android, android-x86

help, i cant find any solution as to why its doing this im trying to build android-x86 but keep getting this error

```
H16TOFW firmware/edgeport/boot2.fw
H16TOFW firmware/edgeport/boot.fw
H16TOFW firmware/edgeport/down.fw
IHEX2FW firmware/emi62/midi.fw
H16TOFW firmware/edgeport/down2.fw
IHEX2FW firmware/whiteheat_loader.fw
IHEX2FW firmware/whiteheat.fw
IHEX2FW firmware/keyspan_pda/keyspan_pda.fw
IHEX2FW firmware/keyspan_pda/xircom_pgs.fw
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/*USERNAME*/Not-so-speedy-one/Projects/android-x86/out/target/product/x86_64/obj/kernel'
make: Leaving directory '/media/*USERNAME*/Not-so-speedy-one/Projects/android-x86/kernel'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
01:23:42 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing enough log. The cause of the problem is probably a lot higher up in the log. In my case it was a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, so I reduced the number of concurrent build tasks. That is the `-j` option in `make`.

Comment: I don't think its a memory issue. I am also facing the same issue used -j1 but didn't help. Found out there is a bug in ninja and meson mentioned here https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1261 it has been fixed in the latest version but I am not sure how to fix my Android build environment. I am compiling Evolution X ROM and getting this error. Increased ARG_MAX, ulimits, MAX_ARG_PAGES but it didn't help at all. Please decode the changes from the link and tell us what to do in the AOSP/Custom ROM build environment.